# JAVA: Fail to launch batch file as as Adminstrator (File with Run as Adminstrator config)

Tags: java

I want launch a batch file with JAVA. So I create a shortcut to this file and config Run as Administrator. I tested the batch file and it run success. But when, I run it with java, the batch file don't run with Administrator and the request is denied.
In java source, I try to call a shortcut of cmd.exe with shortcut configed Run as Administrator. And java source open the commandline with Administrator success.
Please help me.
Here my code:

```
package testfp;

import java.io.*;

public class RunCommand {

String command,result;

public RunCommand(String command) {
    this.command = command;
    run();
    System.out.println(this.result);
}

public void run() {
    try
    {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\Users\\minhlc\\Desktop\\test\\CMD");
        // Fail to open with Administrator
        // Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\Users\\minhlc\\Desktop\\test\\start_apache");          
        //  process.destroy();
        //  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start");
        //  kill_process();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                this.result = this.result + "\n" + line;
            }
        } finally {
        //  br.close();
            };
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void kill_process()
{
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe") ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}

public String get_result() {
    return result;
}
}
```

Thank for reading.

Comment: have you tested the batch by starting it the **same** way, that is, using `start` or even `cmd /c start`?  You can try using/including  the `runas` command

Comment: Yeah. I tried as you asked. But only the CMD is running with Administrator, the start_apache batch file is not running with Administrator. But, if i build project to jar, and run the batch file running with Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the java process with an administration privilege.
Open command line with "Run as administrator" and then

> java -jar you_app.jar

Comment: Wow, it's worked. This is a way. Thank you very much and wish you have a nice day.